# MySQL - Joining two tables without duplicates?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am trying to join. One contains a list of customers, the other is a list of orders. I am trying to formulate a query that will allow me to select all of the customers listed in the table *customers* who have at least one order in the table *orders*. However, I do not want to get duplicates for those customers who have multiple orders. Any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

I know this is probably a common issue, however I have no idea what this type of query would be called so that I could search for an answer. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you try with **DISTINCT**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's much simpler than you may think:

`select distinct(customer_id) from orders;`

Edit: If you actually want to get the full info on the customer,

`select * from customers where customer_id in (select distinct(customer_id) from orders);`

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will give the best chance of success. As the customer and order tables are so large (180 mil records in customers, 70 million in orders) using distinct, especially on customers, is problematic.

Comment: I don't think the distinct is necessary in the subquery - check the EXPLAIN PLAN with and without it to see if there's a difference.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM ORDERS o
                WHERE o.custeromid = c.id)
```

The IN clause is an alternative, but EXISTS works better for duplicates because it returns true on the first duplicate so it doesn't process the entire table.

Comment: Will it not only perform (a lot) better if there is an index on `o.customerid` ?

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann: You'd have to test & see, but exiting on the first match sounds better to me than comparing to all.  Data type could play a role in that too.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that exiting on the first match is probably almost always better. I was just thinking about the worst case and only asking out of theoretical interest :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that EXISTS works better for duplication! Very helpful

Comment: But It will return Customers records only, what if I want to fetch order table records in it self

Answer (score 2):

```
select customers.id, customers.name, count(orders.id)
from customers 
   inner join orders on orders.customer_id = customers.Id
group by customers.id, customers.name
having count(orders.id) > 0
```

Comment: If all you're returning is customer_id and the number of orders, there's no need to do a join. `select customer_id, count(*) from orders group by customer_id` will do the trick.

Comment: My general rule is if the table isn't in the result set, I don't join to it so I don't have to construct GROUP BY/etc to filter out duplicates.

Comment: @OMG: hmmm, interesting rule. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c.id, 
  c.name
FROM
  customer c
    INNER JOIN order o ON o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY 
  c.id,
  c.name
HAVING
  COUNT(o.id) >= 1
```

Can't remember if HAVING or GROUP BY comes first.